# Mac keeps searching for networks even when it's already connected to a network

Tags: macos, network, wifi, airport

My 2013 MacBook Air keeps searching for networks when it is already connected the to internet. This is causing unstable connections which slows down my speed. Is there a remedy for this problem?

Answer (score 4):

It is not a problem and it does not search for network unless you prompt it to.

Only if you click the AirPort menu bar item to look at the list of networks will it start searching to show you what is out there, since it rightly so assumes you wanted to search for networks.

Comment: To be exact, it does search for networks available but does not attempt to connect to them.

Comment: You are correct :)